# X editable backend configuration

Tags: javascript, php, x-editable

I try to use x-editable but i can't find a way to update my database with new data.

In my index.php i have :

```
<a href="#" id="username">superuser</a>
```

and in main.js i have :

```
$('#username').editable({
type: 'text',
pk: 1,
url: 'post.php',
title: 'Enter username'
```

and in post.php :

```
 $pk = $_POST['pk'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
```

and after :

```
          $result = mysql_query('update users set '.mysql_escape_string($name).'="'.mysql_escape_string($value).'" where user_id = "'.mysql_escape_string($pk).'"');
```

When i try, nothing happen, no change in DB, no message, just nothing. If i change     $value = $_POST['value']; and others with real values and i launch post.php directly, sql works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JS**

```
(function(){
         $('a#editlang').editable({
         url: 'post.php',
         escape: false,
         "mode": 'inline',
         "rows": '5',
         "inputclass": 'input-xxlarge',
         validate: function(value) {
            if($.trim(value) == '') {
                return 'This field is required';
            }
          },              
      });  

   });
```

**HTML**

```
<a name="editlang" id="editlang" data-type="textarea" data-pk="1" title="Edit">superuser</a>
```

**in php**

```
$pk = $_POST['pk']; // register id
$value = $_POST['value']; // new name
```

**query**:

```
$result = mysql_query('update users set name = "'.mysql_escape_string($value).'" where user_id = "'.mysql_escape_string($pk).'"');
```

Comment: Works great !! Do you know how to use select with your script ?

Comment: view here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/297/) enough to study this code and try to implement

Comment: Exactly what i need to do (two select) but when i try to reproduce jsfiddle, nothing work, i have only two text : list / dependent list and i can't click on them

Comment: How can i use php while in javascript to load data from sql ?

Comment: yeah you can use while

Comment: I try : <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var sources = {

<?php   $sql="SELECT * FROM batiment"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql); 
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
{  ?>
  1: [{value: 11, text: "<?php echo $result['num']; ?>"}, {value: 111, text: 'A2'}], <?php } ?>

}; but nothing show